# Why is my Python Speech Recognition code not working

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I'm trying to make a simple speech recognition program, and this is the code I have currently.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from speech_recognition import Microphone
from speech_recognition import Recognizer

mic = sr.Microphone()
r = sr.Recognizer()
sr.Microphone.list_working_microphones()

for device_index in Microphone.list_working_microphones():
    Microphone(device_index=4)
    break
else:
    print("No working microphones found!")

with mic as source:
    print("say something:")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    request = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print(request)
```

It used to work, but now it doesn't. What it does do is print "say something:", but it doesn't listen for my voice. I do have pyaudio installed, so that isn't the issue.

My microphone has a little red LED that flashes when in use, so based on that I assume that python is using the microphone.

I've reinstalled all of the packages, and also tried using PocketSphinx, but it doesn't solve the issue.

Why is this? It's a bit infuriating and I don't understand why this could be happening.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: can you `pip freeze` and `which python`? Maybe it's a library or venv issue?

Comment: I am using python 3.10.9

and my pip freeze results are 
pycparser==2.21
pyee==9.0.4
Pygments==2.14.0
pyreadline3==3.4.1
PySocks==1.7.1
requests==2.28.1
rich==13.1.0
selenium==4.7.2
sniffio==1.3.0
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
sounddevice==0.4.5
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
SpeechRecognition==3.9.0
tls-client==0.1.8
trio==0.22.0
trio-websocket==0.9.2
typing_extensions==4.4.0
urllib3==1.26.14
wsproto==1.2.0

Comment: `Microphone.list_working_microphones()` returns a `dict`. It doesn't print anything. You're not actually doing anything in your code to output the contents of the returned `dict`. Documentation: https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst#microphonelist_working_microphones---dictint-str

Comment: _Mic cannot be called_ - Read the docs linked again. Where does it tell you to do `Mic = sr.Microphone()`? You want `sr.Microphone(device_index=device_index)`

Answer (score 0):

Look [at this example code more closely](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst#microphonelist_working_microphones---dictint-str).

You don't need to pull out a variable for `mic`.

Also, that function, as documented says microphones **currently hearing sound**, which probably isn't want you want while working in a quiet environment.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio
m = None
for device_index in sr.Microphone.list_working_microphones():
    m = sr.Microphone(device_index=device_index)
    break
else:
    raise Error("No working microphones found!")

if m is not None:
    print("Mic ready")

    # Now you are ready to recognize
    r = sr.Recognizer()
```

If you want the code from the docs, exactly

```
import Microphone, Recognizer from speech_recognition
```

Then use `Microphone` rather than `sr.Microphone`

Comment: okay thank you, it has helped me establish that my mis is armed. However, it still can't seem to record my voice. I will edit my post with the code that I currently have

Comment: It turns out that the problem was the microphone. For some reason it stopped picking up my voice. I tried another microphone and it worked